# Move many folders and files to their many parent folders

Tags: command-line, files, mv

I need to find all folders with the name "test" and move all folders along with the files inside up a level to their parent folders:

```
html/folder1/js/test -> html/folder1/test

html/folder2/js/test -> html/folder2/test
```

for over 500 folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `for` loop in the directory that is the parent of `folder1`, `folder2` etc (the `html` directory in your example) so first `cd` to it (replace with the real path:

```
cd /PATH/TO/html
```

In this command, if the name of what you want to move is not `test` then replace `test` with the real name or use * to move everything:

```
for dir in ./* ; do mv "$dir"/*/test "$dir"/ ; done
```

This will move all things named `test` (and all their contents, if they are directories) in sub-subdirectories of the current working directory to their parent directories but it will not delete the sub-subdirectories themselves (so `js` in your example, would not be deleted)

**Example:**

before:

```
.
├── 15
│   └── rainbow
│       ├── test
│       └── fun
```

after:

```
.
├── 15
│   ├── rainbow
│   └── test
│       └── fun
```

The command will throw an error for anything that is not a directory with this structure and matching contents, but it still does what you want, so please ignore this, or send the errors away by appending `2>/dev/null`

```
for dir in ./* ; do mv "$dir"/*/test "$dir"/ ; done 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need a bulk command to move more than 500 folders.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues I've now changed my answer completely to do what you want

Answer (score 2):

```
find folder* -name 'test' -exec mv {} {}/../.. \;
```

#### Explanation

`find folder*` Searches in any `./folder*` ([glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) expanded by shell)

`-name 'test'` for files with name `test`.

`-exec mv {} {}/../.. \;` Moves them two levels higher<sup>1</sup>. `{}` is replaced with the found name. The `-exec` option must be terminated with an escaped semicolon. You can do a dry run by adding `echo` before `mv`.

<sup>1</sup> Why two levels up? If we moved the folder into its parent folder, we’d ask to make it a subfolder of its current superfolder, so it will remain in the current place. However, we want to move it to become a subfolder of the parent’s parent. An expanded command will look like `mv folder1/js/test folder1/js/test/../..` which is expanded to `mv folder1/js/test folder1`.

#### Note

Execution of this command will issue warnings like:

```
find: ‘folder1/js/test’: No such file or directory
```

because it’s trying to search in that folder *after* it has been moved. This can be silenced by specifying `2> /dev/null`.

Comment: @Zanna Explanation added to the answer. What is happening in your case?

Comment: Explanation clear. And it does work, if the target is a directory :) Nice!